# How do I make a staff scheduler in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I am playing around with different languages and stumbled across prolog. In order to test myself, I have been trying to set up an employee scheduler for my work. We have a certain time of year where we begin a flex schedule. We can choose from a list of options with varying start times, end times, lunch lengths, and bi-weekly days off: first Friday, first Monday, second Friday, second Monday, and no extra day as options.

I am trying to write a prolog algorithm that will take all these different options and output a schedule that will ensure no more than n employees have one particular option and there is at least one employee for each option. the algorithm should also allow a partial schedule to be entered and have the algorithm spit out different options for the rest of the employees.

I don't know how hard this would be in prolog. But I have seen some fairy large programs reduced to a few lines of code in this language. Does anyone have any suggestions how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gone through a tutorial of any sort?

Comment: Writing a schedule will not be "just a few lines" even in Prolog, although Prolog does lend itself nicely to such problems. I'd recommend finding some good Prolog tutorials and start with simpler programs first to understand the language better. Then you'll be able to start to conceive how you might approach a scheduling program in Prolog. You could also do a Google or Stackoverflow search on "prolog scheduler" and find some instructional examples.

Comment: In addition to what @lurker says, I would begin by defining a really small, almost stupid and unhelpful toy version of this problem and solve that. It shouldn't be too hard to do if you narrow in enough, and then you'll have had a taste of Prolog and your problem and can see for yourself if it'll be worth it.

Comment: You want to take a look at [Constraint Logic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_logic_programming). CLP libraries with interfaces to the Prolog engine come with Prolog implementations of all kinds nowadays. Also take a look at [Answer Set Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming), entirely another approach at constraint solving.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The only structured exposure I have had to prolog has been through the book, Seven Languages in Seven Days. It got me thinking about this problem. I had some sore quick searching for a prolog scheduler, but I mainly come up with task schedules. But I'm guessing now they are more similar to an employee scheduler than I previous ally thought?

Thanks for the insight guys, I'll be sure to do more research. If you guys put your responses as answers I will be sure to up vote them.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use a prolog library called Constraint Logic Programming: https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html

It will help you program an schedule very easy in three steps: Define your variables (for example: Number of employee * Available hours for working during the week) then define a domain for this variables (0 or 1, 0 meaning it doesn't work at that hour and 1 meaning it works at that hour) and finally set your constraints (the ones you wrote on your question).

It might be a little tricky at the beggining but when you understand it becomes really helpfull and easy to use with similar kind of problems.